# mysql query select from multiple, order by date

Tags: php, mysql, join, union, multiple-tables

What's a good and simple way to select from multiple tables and just order everything by date, newest to oldest?

```
 mysql_query("
               SELECT * 
               FROM posts, comments, photos 
               WHERE userID='$session' 
               ORDER BY date");
```

if I wanted to do something like that.

Comment: please give an example including the structure of tables and an example of a result you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION
>   result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the
>   ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one. The following example uses both
>   clauses:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1) UNION 
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2) 
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

> A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized as
>   just shown.
>
> This kind of ORDER BY cannot use column references that include a
>   table name (that is, names in tbl_name.col_name format). Instead,
>   provide a column alias in the first SELECT statement and refer to the
>   alias in the ORDER BY. (Alternatively, refer to the column in the
>   ORDER BY using its column position. However, use of column positions
>   is deprecated.)

-> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT userID, Col1, Col2, Col3, date
      FROM posts
      UNION
      SELECT userID, Col1, Col2, Col3, date
      FROM comments
      SELECT userID, Col1, Col2, Col3, date
      FROM photos ) t
WHERE userID = 123
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Your existing query won't do what you want.  Instead you need to `JOIN` your tables on some common column:

```
SELECT
  posts.*,
  comments.*,
  photos.*
FROM 
  posts JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id
  JOIN photos ON posts.post_id = photos.post_id
ORDER BY posts.date DESC
```

Note that it is often *not* advisable to do `SELECT *` or `SELECT posts.*` in production code. It is typically better to explicitly list the columns you want so you can be sure of the order they arrive in (which matters for `UNION` queries, for example), and if your schema changes.

```
SELECT
  posts.date,
  posts.post_id,
  posts.title,
  posts.etc,
  comments.date,
  comments.user,
  comments.text,
  photos.title
FROM
  posts JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id
  JOIN photos ON posts.post_id = photos.post_id

/* Also, if multiple tables have a `date` column, you'll need to specify which one
   as in `posts`.`date` */
ORDER BY posts.date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes (the query above was just a vague example of which information would be used, but thanks)